# custom variable in rewrite nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

It is an way to make this work?

```
set $test "some|else";
rewrite ^/page/$test/ /index.php?blabla=yes last;
```

Then to work like http://www.demo.com/page/some/ or http://www.demo.com/page/else/

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this, but I haven't tested:

```
if ($request_uri ~* ^/page\/(some|else)$)
{
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?blabla=yes;
}
```

Let me know if it did the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is a good one but my rewrite is complex, with quite a few lines that have portions that are repeated. Therefore I wanted somehow to set a variable to store items such rewrite (some|one|else) and just to call that variable in the rewrite structure's.